# R: Extract values that have the same row and header names

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to extract the values (from a table) that have the same row and column headers. For example, I have a table like this:

```
    A   B   B   C   D   E   E
A   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
B   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  
C   15  16  17  18  19  20  21
D   22  23  24  25  26  27  28
E   29  30  31  32  33  34  35
```

And I want to extract values to get something like this:

```
A   1
B   9
B   10
C   18
D   26
E   34
E   35
```

Any ideas on how I could do this? It has to work for any number of rows and columns, and there could be more than two columns with same headers.

Comment: structure(c(1L, 8L, 15L, 22L, 29L, 2L, 9L, 16L, 23L, 30L, 3L, 
10L, 17L, 24L, 31L, 4L, 11L, 18L, 25L, 32L, 5L, 12L, 19L, 26L, 
33L, 6L, 13L, 20L, 27L, 34L, 7L, 14L, 21L, 28L, 35L), .Dim = c(5L, 
7L), .Dimnames = list(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), c("A", "B", 
"B.1", "C", "D", "E", "E.1")))

Comment: why the downvote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `sapply` across the row/column names to test equality, and then use that index to assemble the data.frame:

```
i <- sapply(colnames(mat), `==`, rownames(mat))    # or i <- outer(rownames(mat), colnames(mat), `==`)

i
##          A     B     B     C     D     E     E
## [1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
## [2,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
## [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
## [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
## [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

df <- data.frame(name = colnames(mat)[colSums(i) > 0],    # if unsure of dimensions, name = if(nrow(mat) > ncol(mat)){rownames(mat)[rowSums(i) > 0]}else{colnames(mat)[colSums(i) > 0]}
                 value = mat[i])

df
##   name value
## 1    A     1
## 2    B     9
## 3    B    10
## 4    C    18
## 5    D    26
## 6    E    34
## 7    E    35
```

---

#### Data

```
mat <- structure(c(1L, 8L, 15L, 22L, 29L, 2L, 9L, 16L, 23L, 30L, 3L, 
    10L, 17L, 24L, 31L, 4L, 11L, 18L, 25L, 32L, 5L, 12L, 19L, 26L, 
    33L, 6L, 13L, 20L, 27L, 34L, 7L, 14L, 21L, 28L, 35L), .Dim = c(5L, 
    7L), .Dimnames = list(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), c("A", "B", 
    "B", "C", "D", "E", "E")))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but for some reason when I try it it does not give me both values for B and E, just one

Comment: Your `dput` of your data shows different column names than the example in the question, which I think is the issue. See the sample data in my edit, which matches what's in the question.

Comment: I see, like B.1 and E.1, do you know how to prevent this?

Comment: I mean how to prevent column names to get ".1" added if there are duplicates when loading the data in R?

Comment: R doesn't like repeated names. You can override them manually by setting the names with `dimnames()<-` or `rownames()<-` and `colnames()<-`. If they follow a pattern, you can `gsub` them out.

Comment: e.g. `dimnames(mat) <- lapply(dimnames(mat), function(x){gsub('\\.\\d+$', '', x)})`

Answer (score 0):

```
tab = structure(c(1L, 8L, 15L, 22L, 29L, 2L, 9L, 16L, 23L, 30L, 3L, 10L, 17L, 24L, 31L, 4L, 11L, 18L, 25L, 32L, 5L, 12L, 19L, 26L, 33L, 6L, 13L, 20L, 27L, 34L, 7L, 14L, 21L, 28L, 35L), .Dim = c(5L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), c("A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "E", "E"))) 
cols = colnames(tab)[col(tab)]
rows = rownames(tab)[row(tab)]
ind = (cols == rows)
a = tab[ind]
names(a) = cols[ind]
```